# Complex Fourier Series. I Might Neeed Some Help On This Problem

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-series

The Problem:

If $f(x) $ is a real funciton, rewrite the integral: $$ \frac{1}{2L} \int_{-L}^{L} |f(x)|^{2} \, dx$$ in terms of the usual Fourier Coefficients, $A_n$ and $B_n$

The attempt: Recall the Fourier Series of $f(x)$ is in the form                         $$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} A_n \cos{ \frac{n \pi x}{L}} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}B_n \sin{\frac{n \pi x}{L}}$$

If we write the cosine and sine terms by exponentials, this would imply that

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} A_n \left(\frac{\exp{\frac{n \pi x}{L}}+\exp{\frac{-n \pi x}{L}}}{2}\right) +  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} B_n \left(\frac{\exp{\frac{n \pi x}{L}}-\exp{\frac{-n \pi x}{L}}}{2i}\right)$$

In simplified terms, the function would be

$$f(x) = A_0 +  \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (A_n - iB_n) \exp{\frac{i n \pi x}{L}}+ \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (A_n + iB_n) \exp{\frac{-i n \pi x}{L}}$$

Now I know that $|f(x)|^{2}$ = $f(x) \overline{f(x)}$ But I am not sure how to find the complex conjugate. Am I on the right track about this?

Thank you for all of your help!

Comment: $$\overline{f(x)} = A_0 +  \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (A_n + iB_n) \exp{\frac{-i n \pi x}{L}}+ \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (A_n - iB_n) \exp{\frac{i n \pi x}{L}}$$ That said, do you really need to use complex series here? The fact that the trigonometric functions form a complete orthogonal system implies an identity (Parseval / Plancherel) of desired form

Comment: Maybe the point of the problem is to prove Parseval's identity.

Comment: @brom: I expect Parseval's identity would be proved in most texts and the object here is to show its utility. As Care Bear said--the idea of orthogonality can be used to reach/use deeper relations. But it wasn't my exercise so I'm not sure.

Comment: @daniel That could well be. I should clarify my original thought: if we already know Parseval's identity, then the problem is somewhat trivial. But I could imagine that this problem comes from a first course in Fourier series which avoids abstract Hilbert space, and that the goal is to prove the result for this particular basis simply by calculation.

Comment: In a nutshell: to get the coefficients in useable form simply multiply $f(x)$ by sine/cosine and integrate over a period. Then you can use Parseval.